# Symfony2.8 Reading data from phpmyadmin database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, symfony-2.8, php-7.2

If i use `utf8_unicode_ci` for columns, i got this in my html page

> منح المركب الجامعي بماليزيا لدراسة  ماجستير تطوير الحلول  في جامعة
>   نوتنغام   =>>??? ?????? ??????? ???????? ?????? ??????? ????? ??????
>   ?? ????? ???????
>
> Arménie =>> Arm�nie

if i change to BLOB and without collation, it works well !!
ALL i do in my controller is this :

```
$this->doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
$this->em = $this->doctrine->getManager();

$typess = $this->doctrine->getRepository('SonataDemoBundle:TypeGrant');
$types = $typess->findAll();
```

for information I use the meta tag for utf8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Recently I made some changes like update tables :

```
update minha_specialite set  name_fr =  CONVERT(CONVERT(CONVERT(name_fr USING latin1) USING binary) USING utf8);
```

for more information here's an example of my website : http://mina7.net/country/140,armenie

Comment: See "question mark", both with and without "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Was it broken before the `UPDATE...CONVERT`?  And it is now broken in the same way, or a different way?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'`.